# ffmpeg produces "is_avc" = false with h264_nvenc & tee muxer

Tags: ffmpeg, centos, nvidia, nvenc

I am using ffmpeg for encoding MKV (Matroska Video files) to 2x MP4 (H264 - 720p Main@L4) & (H264 - 360p Baseline@L3.1).

Having really strange problem when using `-c:v h264_nvenc` and `tee muxer` then the produced output file is having `is_avc=false` even i have checked the same input matroska file with another server running with Intel QuickSync `-c:v h264_qsv` with the same command then the produced output file is `is_avc=true`.

The main goal that i want the `is_avc=true` is because the files must be played using `nginx-vod-module` which requires the AVC video format to be streamed.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- Custom ffmpeg build with NVENC support `ffmpeg version N-91182-gbdf1bbd Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)`
- ffprobe `version 4.0.2-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2007-2018 the FFmpeg developers`
- Running ffmpeg command line with NVENC and tee muxer

  ```
  /root/ffmpeg  -y -t 00:00:50 -i "testinput.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:v]split=2[s0][s1];[s0]scale=-2:720[v0];[s1]scale=-2:360[v1]" -map "[v0]" -map "[v1]" -map 0:a -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v:0 1100k -b:v:1 600k -profile:v:0 main -profile:v:1 baseline -level:v:0 4 -level:v:1 3.1 -ac 2 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -af "aresample=async=1000:first_pts=0"  -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']testoutput.mp4|[select=\'v:1,a\']testoutput-360.mp4"
  ```
- Running ffprobe for the output file to check "is_avc":

  ```
  ./ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams testoutput.mp4
  ```
- My current ffprobe output results are:

  ```
  ./ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_format -show_streams testoutput.mp4
   {
      "streams": [
          {
              "index": 0,
              "codec_name": "h264",
              "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
              "profile": "Main",
              "codec_type": "video",
              "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
              "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
              "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
              "width": 1280,
              "height": 720,
              "coded_width": 1280,
              "coded_height": 720,
              "has_b_frames": 0,
              "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
              "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
              "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
              "level": 40,
              "chroma_location": "left",
              "refs": 1,
              "is_avc": "false",
              "nal_length_size": "0",
              "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
              "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
              "time_base": "1/24000",
              "start_pts": 984,
              "start_time": "0.041000",
              "duration_ts": 1201200,
              "duration": "50.050000",
              "bit_rate": "845035",
              "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
              "nb_frames": "1199",
              "disposition": {
                  "default": 1,
                  "dub": 0,
                  "original": 0,
                  "comment": 0,
                  "lyrics": 0,
                  "karaoke": 0,
                  "forced": 0,
                  "hearing_impaired": 0,
                  "visual_impaired": 0,
                  "clean_effects": 0,
                  "attached_pic": 0,
                  "timed_thumbnails": 0
              },
              "tags": {
                  "language": "und",
                  "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
              }
          },
          {
              "index": 1,
              "codec_name": "aac",
              "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
              "profile": "LC",
              "codec_type": "audio",
              "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
              "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
              "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
              "sample_fmt": "fltp",
              "sample_rate": "48000",
              "channels": 2,
              "channel_layout": "stereo",
              "bits_per_sample": 0,
              "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
              "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
              "time_base": "1/48000",
              "start_pts": 0,
              "start_time": "0.000000",
              "duration_ts": 2401488,
              "duration": "50.031000",
              "bit_rate": "129153",
              "max_bit_rate": "129153",
              "nb_frames": "2346",
              "disposition": {
                  "default": 1,
                  "dub": 0,
                  "original": 0,
                  "comment": 0,
                  "lyrics": 0,
                  "karaoke": 0,
                  "forced": 0,
                  "hearing_impaired": 0,
                  "visual_impaired": 0,
                  "clean_effects": 0,
                  "attached_pic": 0,
                  "timed_thumbnails": 0
              },
              "tags": {
                  "language": "ger",
                  "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
              }
          }
      ],
      "format": {
          "filename": "Leonmusssterben20171080p.mp4",
          "nb_streams": 2,
          "nb_programs": 0,
          "format_name": "mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2",
          "format_long_name": "QuickTime / MOV",
          "start_time": "0.000000",
          "duration": "50.031000",
          "size": "6116472",
          "bit_rate": "978029",
          "probe_score": 100,
          "tags": {
              "major_brand": "isom",
              "minor_version": "512",
              "compatible_brands": "isomiso2avc1mp41",
              "encoder": "Lavf58.17.100"
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Please anyone can help me why is the output video file is getting "is_avc=false" ?

Is there any option to force it ?

Thank you

Comment: Add `-flags +global_header`

Comment: Thank you so much, Solved the problem :)

Comment: @Gyan convert your comment to an answer as it solves the issue, thanks.